# C# application.startuppath

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

In my winforms application I have some code that saves a datagridview/datatable to an XML in the application.startuppath that will usualy be "C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApplication\export.xml but i'm getting an error that it don't have the rights to save this XML file.

When running the application with administrator rights it has no problem.

How can I fix this without needing admin rights?

I'm using this code

```
string xmlPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\export.xml";
            DS1.WriteXml(xmlPath, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, make a folder in AppData.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` is commonly used to get a root directory for storing application data

Answer (score 1):

You need admin rights to write to that folder. There is no way to circumvent that (without disabling UAC).

The only decent solution is: Write to another folder.

Comment: @PandaNL: hello Mr Dutchman ;) did you solve your problem? Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your application is made to run in Administrator mode, I wouldn't touch that folder.

You can use "My Documents/yourapp" or under AppData.